# Parsing a date into a different locale doesn't work

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-date

I am trying to parse a date into a different locale. so instead of *Monday 31 October* it would be *Lundi 31 Octobre* (for French). I'm using the DateFormat class as suggested by the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html). So basically this is the code snippet I'm using:

```
dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.FRANCE);
dateFormat.parse(myCalendar.getTime().toString())
```

But It's throwing a Parsing Exception when I'm executing it.

also `myCalendar.getTime().toString()` yields `Mon Oct 31 12:27:08 GMT+03:00 2016`

Which I think is correct I cannot understand why dateFormat cannot parse it correctly.

Comment: Could you post how you created your pattern for the dateFormat object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is that you are trying to parse a date but you give the wrong format for the formatter.
Instead of converting the calendar date back to string and then parse it you could use the dateFormat.format method.

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, Locale.FRANCE);
Log.d("Time",dateFormat.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
```

The output would be

> jeudi 3 novembre 2016

You can play with the format changing the style or using SimpleDateFormat and define the output format which suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zZ yyyy", Locale.FRANCE);
dateFormat.parse(myCalendar.getTime().toString());
```